# Child list for field " " cannot be created

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, dataset, datamember

I have the following set of codes for adding values to my `DataGridView` through `DataTable` as my datasource. However, it keeps on giving me the error "Child list for field `tbl_main` cannot be created". Anybody can help me identify the problem?

```
dgvMySchedule.Columns.Clear();
dgvMySchedule.Rows.Clear();
dgvMySchedule.ClearSelection();

dataSet.Tables.Add(tbl_main);
dgvMySchedule.DataSource = dataSet;
dgvMySchedule.DataMember = "tbl_main";

tbl_main.Columns.Add("TIME");
tbl_main.Columns.Add("CLASS");

DataRow row;
dgvMySchedule.RowTemplate.Height = 8;
for (int i = 0; i <= 71; i++)
{
    row = tbl_main.NewRow();
    row["TIME"] = i;
    row["CLASS"] = i;
    tbl_main.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a dataset for one table?
Anyway you still need to add the created row to the table and rebind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally realized my mistake. I forgot to initialize my datatable during declaration. I used DataTable tbl_main = new DataTable(); instead of DataTable tbl_main = new DataTable("tbl_main"); The changes pretty much answered my concern. Thank you!

Comment: please mark this as the answer so that this question wont linger as an open ended question.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your `tbl_main` is unnamed, or it has a different name than "tbl_main". There are three possible solutions:

1. Remove the DataSet, instead use `dgvMySchedule.DataSource = tbl_main;`
2. If you need/want the DataSet, add `tbl_main.TableName = "tbl_main";`
3. If you need/want the DataSet, remove the line saying `dgvMySchedule.DataMember = "tbl_main"` (the grid will then automatically use the one DataTable present).

Comment: hi! I finally realized my mistake. I forgot to initialize my datatable during declaration.  
I used   DataTable tbl_main = new DataTable();
 instead of DataTable tbl_main = new DataTable("tbl_main");
The changes pretty much answered my concern. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using binding in winforms.
I had set binding to a non existent field name.